# no interface to huawei stick

Tags: linux, network-interface

using a huawei usb stick on my linux mint works (out of the box) but on my ubuntu server it does not create an interface.

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

/var/log/usb_modeswitch.log (identical output on both machines, except of the 1-10)

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Sat Aug  1 00:04:23 2020

Use global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

Raw args from udev: 1-10:1.0

Bus ID for device not given by udev.
 Trying to determine it from kernel name (1-10:1.0) ...
Use top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10

SCSI dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10
Warning: SCSI attribute "vendor" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "model" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "rev" not readable.
Use interface /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10/1-10:1.0
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  idVendor      12d1
  idProduct     1f01
  manufacturer  HUAWEI
  product       HUAWEI Mobile
  serial        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
  bNumConfigurations    1
  bConfigurationValue   1
  devnum        15
  busnum        1
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
Found packed config collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
Searching entries named: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/12d1:1f01*
Searching overriding entries named: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1f01*
SCSI attributes not needed, move on.

Extract config 12d1:1f01 from collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
config: TargetVendor set to 12d1
config: TargetProduct set to 14db,14dc
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
! matched, now switching
Unbinding driver
Command to be run:
/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -W -D -s 20 -c /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg -u -1 -b 1 -g 15 -v 12d1 -p 1f01 2>&1

Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are expected in the process)
--------------------------------

Read config file: /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg

 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.2 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx


 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1f01
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProductList="14db,14dc"
HuaweiNewMode=1
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled

Use given bus/device number: 001/015 ...
Look for default devices ...
 bus/device number matched
  found USB ID 12d1:1f01
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Get the current device configuration ...
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  Serial No.: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
-------------------------
Using standard Huawei switching message
Looking for active drivers ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
ok:busdev
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)
Check success of mode switch for max. 20 seconds ... Read attributes ...
USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.
 All attributes matched
Mode switching was successful, found 12d1:14dc (HUAWEI: HUAWEI Mobile)Now check for bound driver ...
 no driver has bound to interface 0 yet
Device not in "bind_list" yet, bind it now
Module loader is /sbin/modprobe
Module is active already
Try to add ID to driver "option"
 ID added to driver; check for new devices in /dev
 driver binding failed
Check for AVOID_RESET_QUIRK kernel attribute
 AVOID_RESET_QUIRK activated

All done, exit
```

dmesg

```
[ 4004.412215] usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 4004.561533] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f01
[ 4004.561539] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4004.561542] usb 1-10: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[ 4004.561545] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[ 4004.561548] usb 1-10: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
[ 4004.614909] usb-storage 1-10:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4004.615233] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-10:1.0
[ 4005.668902] scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 4005.685276] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 4005.701070] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[ 4005.732978] sr 6:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[ 4005.733343] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 4005.733589] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 4005.734183] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 4005.764449] sd 6:0:0:1: Power-on or device reset occurred
[ 4005.796221] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4005.959885] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 4006.448382] usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 4006.597604] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc
[ 4006.597609] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4006.597613] usb 1-10: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[ 4006.597616] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[ 4006.853910] cdc_ether 1-10:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[ 4006.854366] usb-storage 1-10:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4006.854751] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-10:1.2
[ 4006.864087] cdc_ether 1-10:1.0 enx001e101f0000: renamed from eth0
[ 4007.887133] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 4007.887717] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4007.888703] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

> [ 4006.864087] cdc_ether 1-10:1.0 enx001e101f0000: renamed from eth0

`enx001e101f0000` is the same interface name on my desktop linux mint and this works, but on my ubuntu server it is missing in the interface list (ifconfig) although it is mentioned in dmesg as you can see.

what i am missing? do i have to create the interface on my own?

Comment: How about `ifconfig -a`? `ls /sys/class/net/`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thx, `ifconfig -a enx001e101f0000` and `ifconfig enx001e101f0000 up` brings the interface up, but no ivp4 address shows up and therefor curl isn't working. any ideas?

Comment: Just seen at the bottom of dmesg that it is being detected as an SD card to do the windows install. There is a mode you need to switch the stick to, to enable the modem

Comment: @JohnnyVegas it is the same output as well as on my laptop with linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

thx to the help i found the solution:

bring up the interface:

```
ifconfig enx001e101f0000 up
```

get ip:

```
dhclient enx001e101f0000
```

test ip:

```
curl http://httpbin.org/ip --interface enx001e101f0000

>> {
>>  "origin": ............
>> }
```

PS: i am note sure but maybe the stick could be in a wrong mode (As JohnnyVegas mentioned). I reconnected the stick and got an info about the GSM modem in `dmesg` but this maybe another story.

```
94780.847155] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[94780.864767] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[94780.864776] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
```